# Expandable search bar in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-forms, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and I  want to do expandable search bar for that I have written below code.

[My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fewyhw)

Now my problem is I want to stop transition after entering value in searchbox on focusout. If searchbar is empty then transition will happen. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must work with ngClass, I add the class "filled" when click and remove if blur and have no value

```
<div class="right">
  <form id="search">
    <input #search type="search" placeholder="Search" [ngClass]="{'filled':filled}" 
         (click)="filled=true" (blur)="filled=search.value?true:false"> 
  </form>
</div>

//remove in your css
//#search input[type=search]
//And add (is the same adding .filled)
#search input[type=search].filled
{
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #4a83c0;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;

}
```

**Update** a button to close can be like

```
<div class="right">
  <form id="search">
    <input #search type="search" [placeholder]="filled?'Search':''" [ngClass]="{'filled':filled}" 
         (click)="filled=!filled" (blur)="filled=search.value?true:false">
         <button class="close" *ngIf="filled" (click)="search.value='';filled=false">X</button>
  </form>
</div>
.close
{
  z-index:10;
  margin-left:-3rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo.. it's working..:) Can you please help me when searchbar have vale then one cross button will show on that button click value of searchbar will clear. can you please help me

Comment: it's only add a button using *ngIf="filled". NOTE:Add a variable filled to your .ts.NOTE2: It's very uggly my button, but it's only an idea

Answer (score 1):

You could put conditional class on your search input that is only there when it has a non-empty value and then target your CSS specifically. Something like:

`<input type="search" [class.has-value]="searchValue" placeholder="Search">`

```
input[type=search]:focus, input.has-value {
   ...
}
```